# Subsetting association rules by conviction

Tags: r, apriori

I have generated a list of association rules that I export to gephi for clustering analysis with the following lines of code:

transactionData <- read.transactions("hilo.csv",sep=",")
transactionRules<-apriori(transactionData, parameter=list(support=0.2,confidence=0.2,conviction=2.0,minlen=2,maxlen=2))
saveAsGraph(transactionRules,file=paste0(outputFilename,".graphml"))

I also calculated the conviction for each rule using the interest measure function of apriori. Is there a way to subset my association rules by the conviction measurement and still be able to export the same file type? Ideally it would be great to include a cutoff for conviction in the actual association mining code, but this does not seem possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Post `dput(head(transactionRules, n = 10))` please.

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand what you are requesting.

Comment: Run the command I posted and then edit your original post and paste the results of that command there.